# Problems detecting USB devices on Windows 8.1

Tags: usb, windows-8.1, drivers, gopro

I cannot pinpoint any reason for which this started happening. The last time I tried it, it worked successfully, and today it just doesn't work.

I'm trying to download photos and videos from a phone and a camera (if it matters, it's a Xiaomi Mi-4c and a GoPro Hero 5 Black). I've connected them by USB and I cannot access them as drives.

They both charge just fine and I can tether WiFi over USB using the phone (which means the cable is fine). I also tested a second cable, which is micro-USB (with an adapter to USB type C) - the cable works fine with a different device, yet still fails for the phone and the GoPro.

The first tip I managed to find online was to update drivers - device manager would say that it's error code `19` or `28` at various times while I was trying to do it. The best guess I could find was a problem with `C:\Windows\Inf\wpdmtp.inf`, suggesting to reinstall it. I tried and it seemed like nothing happened (after clicking to proceed as admin), so in desperation I decided to download this file from the web, guessing it's corrupt (and in my infinite wisdom didn't back it up beforehand). The result is that I now have to shift-restart with the option to ignore driver certificates to even try to install it, which still doesn't help my problem.

I also tried downloading a piece of software called DriverMax - when my phone was in USB tethering mode, it actually allowed me to update drivers for Mi-4c but it doesn't seem to help with trying to access the phone as a drive.

At this stage, I'm completely stumped and would greatly appreciate some help. I have some quite important footage to download from these devices.

Comment: See if you can roll-back to a restore point dating  from before the problem started. That will at least roll-back the botched INF file. WPDMTP is the inf file responsible for generic photo-retrieval support over USB and is an part of Windows itself. You should NEVER replace this with a random file pulled from the internet. At best it breaks things even further, at worst you installed a virus or other malware.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that... Restored the system to a point about two weeks ago. Didn't detect the phone, but when i reinstalled WPDMTP it actually picked it up (and didn't throw anything about lack of certificates at me, which leads me to believe that it did indeed restore the file). Thanks! This is probably not a general answer to the question so might not be helpful to others who would have the same problem, but consider posting it as an answer - I'll accept it.

Comment: Other than these over-intelligent devices, do any other normal USB devices connect and work?